# Changing JTextArea to JScrollPane Causes it to not be visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having an issue with JScrollPanes and JTextArea objects and getting them to work together.

If I just add a JTextArea to my JPanel, it works fine and shows up where I tell it to. However, if I change the contentPane.add(textArea) to contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(textArea)), the textArea is not longer visible and there is no sign of the textarea either.

Here is my code:

```
public docToolGUI() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 611, 487);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(253, 323, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEnterRootDirectory = new JLabel("Enter Root Directory");
        lblEnterRootDirectory.setBounds(253, 293, 127, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblEnterRootDirectory);

        JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
        btnGo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                new ToolWorker().execute();
            }
        });
        btnGo.setBounds(253, 361, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGo);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setBounds(25, 11, 560, 276);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));




    }
```

Comment: Also, ignore the newToolWorker().execute(), its for a different part of the program.

Comment: never-ever do any manual sizing/locating, instead use a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 5):

Try using the constructor for JTextArea that uses 2 int values:

```
textArea = new JTextArea(rows, columns);
```

From the
[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html):

> The two arguments to the JTextArea constructor are hints as to the
>   number of rows and columns, respectively, that the text area should
>   display. The scroll pane that contains the text area pays attention to
>   these hints when determining how big the scroll pane should be.

EDIT: The sample above is a hint for the LayoutManager, but I just noticed that you're not using one.  Unless you have a really good reason not to, you should be.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have to set the bounds of the JScrollPane and you have to make the scroll pane visible instead of the text area.

```
textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
textArea.setEditable(false);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setBounds(25, 11, 560, 276);
scrollPane.setVisible(true);

contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: <teeth gritting> do.not.do.any.manual.sizing.positioning. EVER. Plus the setVisible is not needed (components are visible by default)

Comment: What's wrong with it? Also this was written to fit the original post. But thanks for preventing me from doing this in the future.