# Unable to make the JTextArea scrollable..!

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Here is my code:

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setFont(new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 13));
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setBounds(77, 310, 474, 136);
//contentPane.add(textArea); (edited...still the same problem persists..)


JScrollPane sbrText = new JScrollPane(textArea);
sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
contentPane.add(sbrText);
```

When ever I try with this,the text area is not visible..(I am using Eclipse's Window Builder plugin and layout as "Absolute Layout")..

Comment: You don't need to add the `textArea` to your `contentPane` because it's already included in the `sbrText` afterwards. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more information.

Comment: @MichaelLang: Yup....tried that too mate...no luck..!!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Here is my full code..
https://friendco.de/ui#!/workspace/user/soumava/java-spring-sample/master/employeeloggedin.java

Comment: *"Here is my full code.."*  Not interested.  Where is that SSCCE?  Post it *here*..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: The above link that I provided does contain the full compilable correct example...!!!        
Here is a screenshot: http://oi40.tinypic.com/11jyum0.jpg

Comment: *"does contain the full compilable correct example"*  I did not advise you to post an FCCE, but an ***SSCCE.***  If you had an SSCCE, it could be posted an an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17502210/edit) as opposed to a link I won't visit.

Comment: Okhay...that won't be nescessary now as I've already figured out where I went wrong..So,posted the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have done, the same thingy using `Nested Layout`, have a look at the code example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WelcomeExample
{
    private JPanel headerPanel;
    private JButton logoutButton;

    private JPanel leavePanel;
    private JRadioButton casualRButton;
    private JRadioButton specialRButton;
    private JRadioButton sickRButton;
    private JRadioButton privilegeRButton;
    private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;

    private JTextField leaveDaysField;
    private JButton checkLeaveButton;

    private JTextArea notesArea;
    private JScrollPane notesScroller;

    private JButton applyLeaveButton;

    private String headerText = "<html><body><h1><font " + 
            "color=\"red\">Welcome : </font><font color" +
            "=\"blue\">Code Zero</font></h1></body></html>";

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        headerPanel = getHeaderPanel();
        leavePanel = getLeavePanel();

        contentPane.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contentPane.add(leavePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(getApplyPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getHeaderPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel(headerText, JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
        buttonPanel.add(logoutButton);
        panel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        panel.add(new JSeparator(
            SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel getLeavePanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JPanel leaveHeaderPanel = new JPanel();
        leaveHeaderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        leaveHeaderPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a leave type : "));
        JPanel leaveTypePanel = new JPanel();
        leaveTypePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(
                                FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        casualRButton = new JRadioButton("Casual Leave");
        specialRButton = new JRadioButton("Special Leave");
        sickRButton = new JRadioButton("Sick Leave");
        privilegeRButton = new JRadioButton("Privilege Leave");

        radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioButtonGroup.add(casualRButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(specialRButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(sickRButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(privilegeRButton);

        leaveTypePanel.add(casualRButton);
        leaveTypePanel.add(specialRButton);
        leaveTypePanel.add(sickRButton);
        leaveTypePanel.add(privilegeRButton);

        JPanel applyLeavePanel = new JPanel();
        applyLeavePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(
                                FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        JLabel applyLeaveLabel = new JLabel(
                "Apply for (No. of days) : ", JLabel.CENTER);
        leaveDaysField = new JTextField(5);
        checkLeaveButton = new JButton("Check Leave Availability");

        applyLeavePanel.add(applyLeaveLabel);
        applyLeavePanel.add(leaveDaysField);
        applyLeavePanel.add(checkLeaveButton);

        leaveHeaderPanel.add(leaveTypePanel);
        leaveHeaderPanel.add(applyLeavePanel);

        notesArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        notesScroller = new JScrollPane();
        notesScroller.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                "Leave Note (Max. 200 Characters) : "));
        notesScroller.setViewportView(notesArea);

        panel.add(leaveHeaderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(notesScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel getApplyPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        applyLeaveButton = new JButton("Apply");
        panel.add(applyLeaveButton);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new WelcomeExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: WELCOME EXAMPLE]

Comment: ahhh...just what I was looking for..!!
Thanks maitey..!! :D (Y)

Comment: Do compare it with you code, I am too sure, it does not contains the fuss, we were talking about related to using Layout Managers :-), for the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do `contentPane.add(textArea);`. It is this line that is causing the problem. Comment out this and your code should work fine.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849063/adding-a-scrollable-jtextarea-java) answer, it might help you.

The following code runs fine at my place :

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setBounds(77, 310, 474, 136);

        JScrollPane sbrText = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sbrText);//contentPane.add(sbrText);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

If your code is not running fine then you must have some other error probably related to your `contentpane.`

Comment: As per the previous comment/suggestion I did try that out too... But the problem remains the same..!! :( –

Comment: Also I did try the code snippet in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849063/adding-a-scrollable-jtextarea-java...

Still no luck..!! :-(

Comment: @CodeZero : Have you tried to initialize your `JTextArea` like this `JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);` providing `rows/columns` (don't use the no-argument constructor), that will do. Give some size(dont' use setXxX() methods though, just this thingy alone) in this way to the `JTextArea` so that `JScrollPane` can rely on it. the answer is good, no doubt in that :-), already upvoted this one

Comment: I refered to this example..and specified definite rows and columns..   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273752/changing-jtextarea-to-jscrollpane-causes-it-to-not-be-visible

Still...problem persists..!!  
I'm getting kinda frustrated now..!! :P

Comment: @nIcEcOw : accepted ! but this code is just for illustration purpose that it works. Otherwise I am all for using constructor to determine size.

Comment: @CodeZero : You can check this [__example__](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/TextAreaScroller.java) to verify the thingy works, god knows what you doing at your end :(

Comment: @tejas : I know your answer has been upvoted..    
But I just can't get it to work....still...!!!!
Did everything as per the suggestions..!!! :'(

Comment: @CodeZero : I wasn't talking about the upvote, I was talking about the code that I added and it works.

Comment: Here is my full code..          

https://friendco.de/ui#!/workspace/user/soumava/java-spring-sample/master/employeeloggedin.java

Answer (score 1):

Ok...I finally got it to work...I specified the same set bounds in the scroll pane instead of the text area.. Here is the code.!!! ^_^

```
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        //textArea.setBounds(77, 310, 474, 136);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);         
        scroll.setBounds(77, 310, 474, 136);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
```

Here are the screenshots:

Previous: http://oi40.tinypic.com/11jyum0.jpg
Now: http://oi44.tinypic.com/2s9vdvt.jpg

Comment: That is what you doing wrong, using `Absolute Positioning` __(The Bane of all problems)__ . Instead you should be using Nested Layouts for achieving this `View` :-)

Comment: Haha..well ya..but since I'm new to JAVA programming,with Absolute Positioning I seem to get what I need without much fuss..!! :P

Thanks for all your tips though..!! :)

Comment: When I was new to Java Swing, I use to do the same mistakes as you doing now, but later on I realized how important Layouts are a part of Swing :-)

Comment: Learning is all that counts in the end..!! :P

Comment: even if it appears to somehow solve the problem, it's the *wrong-thingy* to do - there is no way around learning to use *real* LayoutManagers (not that bad excuse called Absolute :-), the earlier the better. -1 (sorry, but this answer is seriously misleading)