# Adding scrollpane on TextArea

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea, horizontal-scrolling

I am making a GUI in which i am adding the horizontal scroll bar in to TextArea because the length of the label/line that will be display in the TextArea is more than the width of the TextArea.

This is my code where I create the pane. But nothing seems to happen....

//create the text area for description and add into the main frame

```
public static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);                                        
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,600));

scrollpanel = new JScrollPane(textArea);    
scrollpanel.setBounds(20, 600, 920, 130);
scrollpanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
scrollpanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Description"));
frmToolToMigrate.getContentPane().add(scrollpanel);
```

Comment: you have to fill the area for the scrollpane to appear

Comment: I filled the scroll area for the same but still nothing seems to happen..

Comment: 1) `textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,600));`  The size of a `JTextArea` can be better specified in the number of rows and columns used in the constructor. 2) `scrollpanel.setBounds(20, 600, 920, 130);`  Doing that (suggesting a size) will probably mean that this nonsense can go.  ..

Comment: .. Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: scrollbar is displaying when i run my code but problem is, suppose the length of the string is more than the width of the textarea then it will no Scrollable.For example suppose i am displaying this statement "Hello I am XYZ . How are you ?". Its display only "Hello I am XYZ . How a" only remaining part is not showing.

Comment: On the otherhand,vertical scroll is working absolutely fine

Comment: One [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17626931/1057230)and [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098108/1057230), hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `setBounds()`, override the scroll pane's [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513). By default, the scroll bars will appear automatically as required. Also consider implementing the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable) interface.

[image]

Comment: As you said, I tried same but when i remove the setbound method and override the scroll pane's getPreferredsize(), textArea is not show into my mainframe.

Comment: Be sure to `pack()` the frame _after_ adding components and  _before_ calling `setVisible`.

Comment: yeah i am sure pack() the frame after adding components before adding components and before setVisible()

Comment: If you are still having problems, it may help to edit your question with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

You can also make textArea as a new class that extends TextArea java class and then implement scrollable.

```
public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea implements Scrollable{

//Whatever you want to do

}
```